# Can the empty set be present in a Sperner family?

Tags: combinatorics

As the title says. I assume it can't be since every subset in the family must be a strict subset and the empty set is a subset of all sets. Just a sanity check.

Comment: What wiki def says is no set in Sperner family is a subset of any other set in the family. So you are right, but your reasoning is not.

Comment: In the degenerate case, I suppose a family containing just the empty set is probably a Sperner family.

Comment: Here's link to wiki def... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner_family

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: for any set $X$, the set $F=\{\emptyset\}$ is a Sperner family on $X$. Indeed, every element of $F$ is a subset of $X$, and there are no two elements of $F$ such that one is a proper subset of the other.

On the other hand, this is the *only* Sperner family containing $\emptyset$. Indeed, if $G$ is a Sperner family containing $\emptyset$, then $G$ cannot contain any non-empty subset $S$ of $X$ (since $\emptyset\subsetneq S$).

Similarly, $\{X\}$ is the only Sperner family in $X$ which contains $X$.